# problem in accessing wifi on ubuntu 16.04 with 4.10 kernel

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, kernel, broadcom

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop version with 4.10 kernel but I am not able to access wifi. I installed broadcom driver using following commands.

```
 $ sudo dpkg -i dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3_all.deb
(Reading database ... 175310 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) over (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...

$ sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 175310 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.10.0-28-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.10.0-28-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
```

and cannot access wifi.

Comment: What's your card model?

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: No, we need your WiFi card model. What use could we possibly have from your graphic card in this contest?

Comment: May i know how can i check?

Comment: So, just to make this clear. You installed some packages for a Broadcom card without knowing if you have one. Is this right? If so, please uninstall them before going on. Anyway, to know the card use `sudo lshw -C network`. Use https://paste.ubuntu.com/ to show us the output please.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nzBt4JkM5J/

Comment: Are you sure you have a WiFi card and that it works? Because it's not listed in the hardware. Post please your full hardware list with `sudo lshw`

Comment: I m not sure. Please check https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Hn6fhs9r8s/

Comment: To me it doesn't look like you have a WiFi card. On that Dell model is optional, are you sure that you bought it with?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Answer (score 1):

As shown in your `lshw`, you simply don't have a WiFi card.

A solution to this problem would be to buy one and install it.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried to restart your network-manager. 
Here is the code for that

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If that doesn't work, then install the missing firmware with

```
cd /lib/firmware

sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
```

Then reboot into kernel 4.10

The iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode file is not in the linux-firmware package for 14.04

Comment: Yes i did but still same issue.

Comment: I cannot use wget as there is no internet . Also  i checked one more thing there is no enable wifi option (screenshot of my screen) https://ibb.co/n2qMbn

Comment: try to connect your laptop to internet through any means such as using LAN wire, USB modem, data card or bluetooth tethering and then update your system and restart.